SUM this column
I want to SUM the total amount of the user payments, but the result was different.
I tried to use JOIN to combine 3 table and add the list user_id, list survey, and total amount for each user. But, the total amount result wasn't the same as I did in separate table.
SELECT
users.user_id,
COUNT(DISTINCT participations.survey_id) as total_survey,
SUM(amount) as total_amount
FROM `angket.users` as users
RIGHT JOIN `angket.participations`as participations
using (user_id)
RIGHT JOIN `angket.payments`as payments
USING (user_id)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1


SELECT
user_id,
SUM(amount) as total_amount
FROM `angket.payments` as payments
LEFT JOIN `angket.users`as users
USING(user_id)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1



Please provide a [mre] with sample (raw) data for all tables involved, and the results you are trying to achieve. In addition, please do not use images for data, use table markdown.

Your RIGHT JOINs are going to produce more records to sum, right?  That result doesn't seem unexpected.

This question is about MySQL, but the problem and solution are the same for most SQL dialects.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The answer is relatively easy, once you compare the sums in one and the other query:

User_id 'U0000' participated 8 times
User_id 'U0001' participated 4 times
User_id 'U0002' participated 3 times

this lead to an erronous partial Cartesian product, so that the occurrences of the various payments were multiplied by the number of participations, so that the amounts were summed 8, 4 and 3 times in the query joining with partitipations.
But - as you need a count distinct from participations , try two different groupings in two nested queries:
SELECT
  users.user_id
, COUNT(DISTINCT participations.survey_id) as total_survey
, total_amount
FROM angket.users as users
RIGHT JOIN angket.participationsas participations
USING (user_id)
RIGHT JOIN (
  SELECT
    user_id
  , SUM(amount) AS total_§amount
  FROM angket.payments 
  GROUP BY user_id
) sumpayments
USING (user_id)
GROUP BY 1, 3
ORDER BY 1


